# Android: How to measure the effect of ad blocking in terms of the number of blocked ads and the network bandwidth consumption?

Tags: android, bandwidth, adblock

I am currently developing a browser running on Android. I want to add an ad blocking feature which will additionally show the effect of it in terms of the following metrics:

1. the number of ads blocked by the blocker
2. the amount of network bandwidth consumption saved by the blocker

Do you have any ideas how to implement a component for them?

In CM browser which has ad blocking feature, the above values are currently shown to users. The first one is shown every time when users load a new web page. The second one is displayed daily basis on Setting.

My Android browser uses `WebView`, and use `shouldInterceptRequest` callback methods in `WebViewClient` to block the ads. So, ads are blocked in a way that making requests for an ad is just skipped if the URL specified in a request is matched with one of the filters.

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

The followings are what I tried so far for each one.

For the first,

- I just counted the number of the requests that are blocked in the `shouldInterceptRequest` method. However, I realized it soon that it does not always show the number of ads that should have been shown but actually blocked. I think it's because multiple requests can be made to display an ad. It could include the requests for retrieving javascript codes or something else.

For the second,

- I tried to use Content-Length field in HTTP response with the following code snippet.

  ```
  URL u = new URL(url);
  URLConnection urlConnection = u.openConnection();
  urlConnection.connect();
  int size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  ```

  The problem is that `Content-Length` is not always correct. In most cases, it is -1.

Are there any libraries I can use for them? I welcome any help or comments.

Thanks,

Comment: For network bandwidth usage, you do realize you are asking a 'what is in the box' without opening the box type of question. Especially hard as ad assets come and go every second (i.e. no Christmas sale ads in April). You could open the box by either downloading the ad once to record the size or have a server do it and your app ask your own server what the size is.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks. You're right. It's hard to measure the network bandwidth usage, especially for ads. However, If I can measure it just one time when a web page is loaded and do not need to consider the bandwidth usage that is made afterward. do you have any idea for it?